# git push --mirror gives "failed to push some refs"

Tags: git

I am trying to create a script that can mirror my git repository to another repository. Everything goes fine, but it it keeps saying

```
[remote rejected] refs/pull/xx/head -> refs/pull/xx/head (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
```

The repository is cloned to a folder on my computer, and then pushed to another git. All files and history is cloned and pushed as it should, but this "error" keeps coming up. What can i do?

[image]

This is my script

```
git clone --mirror https://path1.com/_git/fredagsproject1
cd fredagsproject1.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://path2.com/_git/fredagsproject2
git push --mirror
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you run `git push`, you have your Git call up another Git over the Internet-phone.  Your Git hands their Git some objects (commits and the like), and then sends their Git a pile of requests:

- please set `refs/heads/branch` to point to commit `1234567...`
- please set `refs/tags/v1.2` to point to annotated tag object `fedcba9...`

and the like.

Using `git push --mirror` tells your Git to ask *their* Git to set *every* name that you have, using exactly the same name in the request.  As the image shows (and you've copied to a text line), many of these names have the form:

```
refs/pull/xx/head
```

for some two-digit `xx` sequence.

Their Git is simply saying *No: I refuse to set that name.*

You can *try* adding `--force`, which tells your Git to send a command—*set these names!*—instead of a polite request, *please set these names*, but take a look at the *reason* that their Git returned along with the refusal:

> ```
> The current action can only be performed by the system.
> ```

That seems to say: *Hands off this name!  I reserve it for **my** use, how dare you ask me to change **my** `refs/pull/73/head`!*  In which case the command form (as opposed to the polite request form) is likely to be refused as well.

Note that ref-names of the form `refs/pull/number/head` and `refs/pull/number/merge` are used internally by, among others, GitHub for its management of pull requests.  It's likely that you should not even attempt to set these names—so if your attempts are failing, that's probably a *good thing*.

Comment: Thank you for giving your time to explain what is happening. I did not have any luck of using --force. But as you said, this would not be any good idea anyway. I will mark this answer as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up to the answer by @torek. To avoid the remote rejected errors, try the following commands instead of `git push --mirror`.

```
git push --all
git push --tags
```

The `--all` option pushes all the refs under `/refs/heads/`, and
the `--tags` option pushes all the refs under `/refs/tags`.

Most remotes will happily accept those refs. While it is possible to to use `--force` option with above commands, it is a destructive operation. Be extremely careful while exercising this option.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. git refuses the push because option --mirror and --all/--tags cannot be used together. Probably it remembers the --mirror from the clone.